# Getting Error with SharePoint web service from Acrobat

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, web-services, pdf, soap

I am using following code to get data from SharePoint List in Acrobat using javascript:

```
var oAuthenticator ={ UsePlatformAuth: "true"}; 
var oRequest = {
    soapValue: '<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">'+
  '<listName>' + listId + '</listName>'+
  '<viewName>All Items</viewName>'+
  '<query></query>'+
  '<viewFields>Title</viewFields>'+
  '<rowLimit></rowLimit>'+
  '<queryOptions></queryOptions>'+
  '<webID></webID>'+
'</GetListItems>'
};

var cAction = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems";    
var ver = SOAPVersion.version_1_2; 
var response = SOAP.request ({
     cURL: siteUrl + "_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
     oRequest:oRequest,
     cAction:cAction,
     oAuthenticate:oAuthenticator,
     cResponseStyle: SOAPMessageStyle.Message,
     bEncoded:false,
     cVersion:ver
 });
```

Here in response I am getting `undefined` as it is showing `401 authentication error` in fiddler for this service call.

What Authentication I can add here to get it working??

Comment: Are you running this soap call from the SharePoint page?

Comment: No i m running it from Acrobat PDF file menu